# How do I make an image square?

Tags: css, image

I have this event carousel on my website and the chosen image is a rectangle. I want it to be a square, but I don't know how. I can't find anything that will help me on google regarding this question I have.

My website is https://musikhuset.nu (Swedish)

I want it to be a square on every picture on the event carousel if that was unclear, not just one.

[image]

I have tried writing:

```
.mec-event-image{
    width:287px;
    height: 287px;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please read [ask] and post here a [mcve]

Comment: In CSS, `width:287;` won't work - you need to use a unit, like `width:287px;`

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  width: 287px;
  height: 287px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked! But it's kind of cropped in a weird way now? The chosen image is a square aswell but the full image is still not shown.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641669/johannes) pointed out: You need to add units to CSS-size definitions. For your case, you want to add `px` (pixels) to your numbers.

Generally you can also use other units, most common are `em`, `%`, `vw` & `vh`. For a more complete list, see [CSS Units by W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php).

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to put it in my post, but I did use PX.